# Having both C and C++ files in XCode project failing

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, sqlite

I'm trying to use information from a sqlite database in my C++ project. I downloaded the sqlite amalgamation and added `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3.c` to my project, and added `#include "sqlite3.h"`to my precompiled header file.

However, Xcode no longer finds standard headers such as `algorithm`, `cassert`, `cfloat`, etc. 
The specific error is this:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - 'algorithm' file not found
```

If I remove the two sqlite files from the project, the headers can be found again. If I rename the `sqlite3.c` file to a `.cpp` file, the headers are also found again. Removing `#include "sqlite3.h"` does not change anything.

However, I can't leave it as a `.cpp` file because it gives errors since it uses some things that don't seem to be compatible with C++.

Is there a way to have both C and C++ files in the same XCode project? (Or another way to include the sqlite library?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get things to work, I had to enclose my all of my `#include`s with an `#ifdef __cplusplus` and `endif`. I don't quite know all of the mechanics behind why.